# How do I add a feed for a tag in a chat room?

Tags: support, chat, feed

If I want, say, all [lord-of-the-rings] posts to go to my chat room, what do I do in the add feed bit? What URL do I paste there?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you figured it out, but for others' future reference:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

And I think the actual creation screen is obvious enough:

[image: Creation screen]

The address of the feed is http://[site].stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/[tag name], e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/lord-of-the-rings, and can be found on the hover tag:

[image: Feed]

Note that only the room owner or a chat mod can edit the feeds for that room.

Comment: Thanks, though actually I meant that I don't know what URL I paste in that thingy, but I found that out with the same question on Meta Stack Overflow. Still +1